# Convex hull and least area discs in Riemannian 3-manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

$\DeclareMathOperator\Conv{Conv}$Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian 3-manifold and $\gamma \subset M$ a simple closed curve that bounds a *least-area disc* $D$ - a disc that minimizes the area among all discs bounded by $\gamma$.
Let $\Conv(\gamma)$ be the convex hull of $\gamma$, i.e, the smallest convex subset of $M$ containing $\gamma$. When $M = \mathbb R^3$ (with the standard Euclidean metric), it is a well-known result that $D \subseteq \Conv(\gamma)$.

*Question 1: What (topologcial, metric) conditions need to be satisfied on $M$, along with possible restrictions to $\gamma$, so that $D \subseteq \Conv(\gamma)$ holds true ?*

I only know of partial results to this question, such as when $M$ is equipped with a complete metric of bounded sectional curvature and positive injectivity radius, then the above will hold true for all sufficiently small simple closed curves $\gamma$. This is a consequence of a result proven by Joel Hass and Peter Scott in [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1988-310-01/S0002-9947-1988-0965747-6/S0002-9947-1988-0965747-6.pdf) (Theorem 6.3). I am very interested in whether this has been generalized even further as of today.

Note also that when $M = \mathbb R^3$ and $X \subset M$ is any subset, $\Conv(X)$ is simply the set of all convex combinations of points in $X$. Orangeskid, a user over at stackexchange has brought to my attention in his [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672336/estimate-on-size-of-convex-hull) to a similiar question I posed a week ago that this, along with the convexity of the norm function, is enough to show that \begin{equation}
\text{Diam}(\Conv(X)) = \text{Diam}(X) \end{equation} always holds true. This means that on $\mathbb R^3$, taking the convex hull of a set does not increase the diameter.

*Question 2: What (topological, metric) conditions need to be satisfied on $M$, so that $\text{Diam}(\Conv(X)) = \text{Diam}(X)$ holds true for sufficiently nice subsets $X \subset M$ ?*

The problem here lies in the fact that a general $3$-manifolds lacks a vector space structure, thus both the feasible description of a convex hull, as well as the "convexity" of the metric are not available any more. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Both statements hold in [Hadamard manifolds](https://Hadamard%20manifold).

Denote by $K$ the closed convex hull of $X$ in a Hadamard manifold $M$.

**Area-minimizing disc.**
The closest-point projection $M\to K$ is short (= distance-nonexpanding).
Therefore an area-minimizing disc $D$ with boundary in $K$ must lie in $K$.

**Diameter.**
The balls in $M$ are convex.
Let $D=\mathrm{diam}\, X$.
Denote by $L$ the intersection of all closed $D$-balls that contain $X$.
Note that $\mathrm{diam}\, L=D$.
Since $L\supset K\supset X$, we get $\mathrm{diam}\, K=D$.